# Challenges updating ubuntu from 16.04 to newest version, seemingly related to fuse vs fuse3

Tags: updates

I have an older computer that I am trying to upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to the newest version. This would normally be a simple `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade` sort of thing, however this is not functioning here. I've tried several things (not listed since nothing has seemed to even make a dent in the issue) but I am always running into this fuse related error no mater what I do. Infact, when I try to install any package now with apt, I get this same fuse error.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Example:

```
Desktop$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fuse-overlayfs : Depends: fuse3 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is installed
                  Depends: libfuse3-3 (>= 3.2.3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: and to address one obvious question,`sudo apt update` does update a few things, but returns i.e `W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 160286925` for many others

Comment: Thought this might be the case. Ok well, clean slate it is then!

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is *community* support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Comment: The *release-upgrade* path from 16.04 is to 18.04; which is off-topic here, as 18.04 like 16.04 is also EOSS & *unsupported* by the community. After that upgrade you'll need to repeat the process to go to 20.04 (*that is a supported upgrade on sites such as this, as 20.04 is the oldest supported release on-topic here*), then again to 22.04, then if you do wish to go to the latest; you've two upgrades still to go at that point currently (to 23.04, then 23.10 which is the latest, but not a LTS).

Comment: Your signature issue is because you've **not** applied security fixes to update your certificates; they are available for 16.04 & 18.04 when ESM is *enabled*.   Those may not however stop you from *do-release-upgrade* or an actual upgrade to the next release (*at least not to a supported release; I've not tested it to an EOSS release lke 18.04 - but it's what I'd try*).  You can *non-destructively* re-install desktop systems (it's far quicker) but not really server installs (*far more complicated*).

Answer (score 3):

For most users, the fastest, simplest, and least fraught way is to simply backup your data and then reinstall a much newer release of Ubuntu.

- You could easily waste days troubleshooting your 16.04 install to make it ready for release-upgrading...then testing and troubleshooting troubleshooting problems in 18.04...then again in 20.04...and yet once more in 22.04.
- Your 16.04 system, if not a Pro subscriber, has perhaps not received security updates in over two years. Yet another reason to wipe it and reinstall.